# Initializing array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an array which should hold constant values for entire life of Excel.
I get error "Invalid outside procedure" while I am trying to initialize my array with numbers:

```
Public Aone(1 To 9) As Variant
Aone = Array(0.47589, 0.23795, 0.16656, 0.16656, 0.03569, 0.04759, 0.00119, 0.00119, 0.00119)
```

Comment: Only constants can be defined outside of a sub or function in VBA.  Using a PUBLIC FUNCTION with a return type of variant will replace what you have above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well Finally got a solution,

as @A.S.H suggested but with little twist:

at "ThisWorkbook" module

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Aone(1) = 0.47589
    Aone(2) = 0.23795
    Aone(3) = 0.16656
    Aone(4) = 0.16656
    Aone(5) = 0.03569
    Aone(6) = 0.04759
    Aone(7) = 0.00119
    Aone(8) = 0.00119
    Aone(9) = 0.00119
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

In module Module1

```
Private ar As Variant
Function Aone(idx As Integer) As Double
    On Error GoTo FillArray
    Aone = ar(idx)
    Exit Function
FillArray:
    ar = Array(0.47589, 0.23795, 0.16656, 0.16656, 0.03569, 0.04759, 0.00119, 0.00119, 0.00119)
    Aone = ar(idx)

End Function
```

Comment: ok, there is a better approach to do this anyway, I am preparing it.

Comment: @ygaft the edited answer gets you an answer with indexes from 0 to 8. If you want range 1 to 9, you can make it Aone = ar(idx - 1).

Comment: Thanks, as I posted your first option was good with a twist :)
Have a great day